# Setting up a Java EE development environment in Debian

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, installation

I have installed Debian in a virtual machine with openJDK8 and Apache Tomcat8, I also downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers from the Eclipse website.

Now I would like to write my first Hello World servlet application in Eclipse (menu File > New > Dynamic Web Project). In "Target Runtime" I should choose Tomcat but the pulldown menu doesn't show anything.

It seems to be difficult. Any suggestions?

Comment: Set up Tomcat in Eclipse before creating a new project. A quick Google search will lead you to something like [this](https://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-and-install-apache-tomcat-server-in-eclipse-development-environment-ide/)

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use eclipse? I would recommend netbeans as it works out of the box (no plug-ins to install). EE pundits say you lose 2 days (minimum) getting eclipse up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not install sever plugin in eclipse.
You need to go to **Help>Eclipse Marketplace** in eclipse and search and install the plugin then you will be able to see server in drop down.

Comment: Thanks, I did it. But I still have to specify the tomcat installation directory. I don't know what I have to choose on linux. Tomcat is already running.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way without any plugin, just:

```
File ⇒ New ⇒ Other... ⇒ Servers ⇒ Server ⇒ Next >
```

and then choose the **right** server. I had to choose Tomcat v8.5 instead of 8.0. This was the problem.